# Are object.x and object.y object's position in browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure about this properties, because I can't find them on w3c. Are they real position in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that object.x and object.y are the positions of the element in the browser, however they're not always supported (by browser and also it may not always be relevant for an element)

An approach for identifying position: [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript)

See javascript reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp for all the positioning properties available

Documentation that x and y can provide position information: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/javascriptobject

Answer (score 0):

No.

From a test I just performed:

```
> document.body.x
undefined
```